# How to insert data in purchase tabele with diffrent price without data dedundancy

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, entity

i have create a table name as purchase

```
 CREATE TABLE purchase(
item_id NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
purchase_qty VARCHAR2(50),
sup_name  VARCHAR2(50),
purchase_price NUMBER (10)
);
```

and insert data

```
    INSERT INTO purchase
VALUES(0001,170,'MG Trading',100);
```

I want to be insert same item name with different price such as 120 How it possible because item_id =primary key and if insert to anther row with out PK it's effect data data redundancy problem , then i have remove primary key and insert another value

```
INSERT INTO purchase
VALUES(0001,30,'abc_company',120);
```

now total item qty 170+30=200 a customer need  qty 180 how can i sale it ?? because my item is oil type product  and can not print barcode for oil
this entity crate  a  oil pump application

Comment: Your data model seems messed up.  `ItemId` should be the primary key to the *Items* table, not the *Purchases* table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff   if i have create another table  item_id  pk and  purchase table item_id  FK  i can soluation it for my oil type product ??

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right. You should have one register in the Purchases table with many registers in the Items table. Someone purchase sth with many items in this purchase.

Comment: @GordonLinoff previously i was create item table  and also do it  but my question is hear same item id different type of price  product is oil such as  diesel octane mobile i can not attached barcode for the product and i can not  store different place   how can i sale it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two register with the same value to the Primary Key, doesn't matter the other columns values.

I think, as @GordonLinoff suggested, your model is the problem.

You should make something like [this](https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_800_800/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAJxAAAAJGI4YzZkZTRhLTg1M2ItNGJkOC04ZmVjLTNjMGQyY2Y2NjRlYQ.png).

Comment: i have all ready create the model   this is ,   https://www.dropbox.com/s/5a0qbwc63wbdf63/entity.PNG?dl=0

Comment: You cannot put the ItemId in the Purchase table. If so, you would be able to insert one item only into a purchase record. You really need to understand about relational database modeling. Please, read it: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561 - I think this article is going to help you to modeling your database perfectly.

Comment: good articles  i have all ready learn RDMS ,  if i want a create application CNG fuel system  how do i create RDMS database?  fuel price always up down, i think you identified my problem ,Thanks